# Qt request never trigger the finished() signal

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

i have something really strange i have this code :

i think i know what is wrong but i dont know how to fix it . 
this is what i have :
when i put break point in int test = 0; 
it getting there before it gets to httpFinished() slot in the HttpClient , mybe this is the problem ? 
in the main.cpp

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@while (i.hasNext())
{
i.next();

ThreadWorker* pThreadWorker = new ThreadWorker();
pThreadWorker->setUrl(sUrl);
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(pThreadWorker);
}
QThreadPool::globalInstance()->waitForDone();



---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void ThreadWorker::run()
{
  startWork();
}

void ThreadWorker::startWork()
{
 m_pHttpClient = new HttpClient();
 m_pHttpClient->startRequest(m_url);
 int test = 0;


}

--------------------------------- HttpClient  based on the http example from Qt -----------------------------------

HttpClient::HttpClient()
{
  m_networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
  connect(m_networkManager, SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)),
            this, SLOT(slotAuthenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)));

 #ifndef QT_NO_OPENSSL
    connect(m_networkManager, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)),
            this, SLOT(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)));
 #endif
}



void HttpClient::startRequest(QUrl url)
{
   m_url.setUrl("http://qt.nokia.com/");
  QNetworkRequest request; 
  request.setUrl(m_url);

 reply = m_networkManager->get(request);


 connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
         this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));

 connect(reply,SIGNAL(finished()),
            this, SLOT(httpFinished()));

    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
            this, SLOT(httpReadyRead()));

    connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)),
            this, SLOT(updateDataReadProgress(qint64,qint64)));


}
```

the httpFinished() function that is under private slots: never triggered , why ?

**UPDATED THE QUESTION**

Answer (score 1):

Since the `HttpClient` and `QNetworkAccessManager` objects are created within the thread, they automatically belongs to that thread (see [`QObject::moveToThread`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qobject.html#moveToThread)), and they  both needs an event loop running in that thread, for QNAM to do any work at all, and for your `QObject` derived class to be able to execute the slots.

You could add a call to `QThread::exec()` in `run()` to run that event loop (if you were using `QThread`):

```
void Thread::run()
{
    startWork();
    exec();
}
```

or create and start a `QEventLoop` whose `quit()` slot has to be connected somewhere to stop the loop (for example a `finished()` signal in the class `HttpClient` that you would emit when the work is done):

```
void ThreadWorker::run()
{
    startWork();
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(m_pHttpClient, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec(); 
}
```

Also, [since Qt 4.8](http://blog.qt.digia.com/2011/04/29/threaded-http-inside-qnetworkaccessmanager/), `QNetworkAccessManager` is multithreaded, so you might not need to use threads yourself.

Comment: Thank i know that in 4.8 it is mt but i need to do more work in the thread not only http req , how the thread knows its done?

Comment: @user63898 The thread doesn't stop by itself, you need to call its slot `quit()` (or connect it to the reply `finished()` signal) to stop the event loop and the thread.

Comment: @user63898 Sorry, I thought you were using QThread, I just added some code to do the same thing for QThreadPool/QRunnable. But really, QThread would make more sense as you wouldn't need to stop the event loop betweeen 2 tasks on the same thread.

Comment: also i did it but now i have new problem :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002747/qt-request-always-returns-status-code-0