# Qt http get request always returns status code 0 in multi thread mode requests

Tags: c++, http, request, qthread

i have simple request method inside simple http client , that QRunnble worker is invoking
all the returners of the request are status 0 ,
what more i spotted after few tests is, when i give the app to run with 1 thread that is
only 1 url to process its working fine and i get status 200 .
i suspect something in my http client code is worng and does not support  multi thread mode
here is my full httpclient code:

this is the code of the request :

```
 #ifndef _HttpClient_
#define _HttpClient_
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QUrl>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QSslError;
class QAuthenticator;
class QNetworkReply;
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class HttpClient : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT   
    public:
        HttpClient(QFile* file,QMutex* mutex);
        ~HttpClient();
         void startRequest(QString& url);
    public slots:
    #ifndef QT_NO_OPENSSL
        void sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,const QList<QSslError> &errors);
    #endif
    private:
        QString m_sUrl;
        QUrl m_url;
        QNetworkAccessManager* m_networkManager;
        QNetworkReply *reply;
        int httpGetId;      
        void HandleNetworkError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError& networkError,
                                QNetworkReply *networkReply);   
};

#endif

------------------------------------

#include "HttpClient.h"
#include <QMutexLocker>
#include <QTextStream>

HttpClient::HttpClient()
{
     m_networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
}
HttpClient::~HttpClient()
{
;
}

void HttpClient::startRequest(QString& url)
{
     QNetworkRequest request;
     request.setUrl(QUrl(url));
     QEventLoop loop;
     reply = m_networkManager->get(request);
     connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
     loop.exec();
     LOG_MSG("Is UrlAlive?:"+url.toStdString())
     QString ApiResponse;
     QByteArray data=reply->readAll();
     ApiResponse.append(QString::fromUtf8(data));
     int iStatusCodeV =  reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
     if (reply->error()) {
        QNetworkReply::NetworkError networkError = reply->error();
        HandleNetworkError(networkError,reply); 
     }
    QString s = QString::number(iStatusCodeV);
    reply->deleteLater();
    reply = 0;

}
void HttpClient::HandleNetworkError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError& networkError,QNetworkReply *networkReply)
{
        if(networkError != QNetworkReply::NoError)
        {
            QString err = networkReply->errorString();
            LOG_MSG("HttpClient::HandleNetworkError:"+err.toStdString());
        }
}
#ifndef QT_NO_OPENSSL
void HttpClient::sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,const QList<QSslError> &errors)
{

        reply->ignoreSslErrors();   
}
#endif
```

all of this called from QRunnble method that looks like this :

```
void ThreadWorker::run()
{
    QMutexLocker lock(_m);
    startwork();
    lock.unlock();


}

void ThreadWorker::startwork()
{
    m_pHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    //each thread gets unique url
    m_pHttpClient->startRequest(m_url);

}
```

why its failing all the time?

Comment: Have you checked the server-side logs to see what happens there? Have you checked that all other functions returns "okay"?

Comment: There is no server side its http client that making http requests to web sites

Comment: Yes, so there has to be a web _server_ somewhere. Try to connect to a server you have control over first, so you can check both client and server side.

Comment: i just put the url in the browser and i see the site just fine

Comment: i think i spotted the problem , its in multi thread mode happen
when i just process 1 url its working , i updating the question